# Let $R=M_2(\mathbb R)$. Show that there are nonzero elements $x\in R$ that have the property that $x^2=0$. Determine all elements...

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

> Let $R=M_2(\mathbb R)$. Show that there are nonzero elements $x\in R$ that have the property that $x^2=0$. Determine all elements $y\in R$ that have the property that $y^2=1_R$.

I think that I have the nonzero elements $x\in R$ part. I would determine a matrix such as $x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, since this gives $x^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

But the only elements $y\in R$ that have the property $y^2=1_R$ would be $y=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $y=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Or am I overthinking this?

Comment: There are more elements satisfying $y^2=1$, such as $y=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: So then the matrix $y=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ would also work. I'm thinking these are the only 4 because I tried constructing other matrices but couldn't get $y^2=1_R$.

Comment: @BennieJosephVassallo There are infinitely many.  One way to find all of them is to pick four variables for the coefficients of $y$, and solve the four equations in these variables you get from $y^2 = 1_R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of examples in your second case, like $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ -\frac{3}{2} & -2 \end{pmatrix}. $$  How can you find them all? Well,  $$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 + bc & b(a + d) \\  c (a+d) & d^2 + bc \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}   $$
You see that either the trace of your matrix must be zero, or $b = c = 0$.  If $b = c = 0$, then $a^2 = d^2 = 1$, so $a, d = \pm 1$.

If the trace is zero, pick any two nonzero real numbers $a$ and $b$. Then since $a^2 + bc = 1$, solving for $c$ gives $c = \frac{1 - a^2}{b}$ and the matrix is  $$ \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ \frac{1-a^2}{b} & -a \end{pmatrix} $$

If $a = -d$ and $c = 0$, $b$ can be anything, but we have to have $a^2 = 1$, so $a = \pm 1$ and we get matrices of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \pm1 & b \\ 0 & \mp 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
and similarly when $b = a + d=0$ and the trace is zero.

Now, if $a = 0$, then $bc = \pm 1$, so $c = 1/b$.  This shows $b$ can be any nonzero real number and gives the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{b} \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
You can do a similar thing to find all the matrices whose square is $0$.

Comment: I understand up until if the trace is 0. I don't understand how you determine the matrix $y=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\{1-a^2\over b}&-a\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your question and in order to deal with a case I overlooked. Do you understand now?

Comment: Yes, thank you that helps so much. I am working now to rewrite my proof to find all the matrices whose square is 0, since I messed that up. I think I'll be able to prove it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach to finding all $M$ with $M^2 = I$:

Since $M^2 - I = 0$, the minimal polynomial of $M$ must be $X-1$, $X+1$, or $X^2-1$.  In the first case, we have $M=I$.  In the second case, we have $M=-I$.

In the third case, the characteristic polynomial is also $X^2-1$, so we have $\operatorname{tr}M = 0$ and $\det{M} = 1$.  Similarly, we can check that any such matrix is a solution to $M^2=I$.